# How to modify a Sharepoint navigation bar

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am studying the Sharepoint V1.0 API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) provided by Microsoft and was wondering if there was an end-point capable of changing the order of a team Navigation menu within Sharepoint automatically without human actions.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such api to edit SharePoint navigation link orders, you can only manage the order in the Edit of navigation bar. Please refer to following document

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca#:~:text=Use%20drag%20and%20drop%20to,position%20in%20the%20navigation%20area](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca#:%7E:text=Use%20drag%20and%20drop%20to,position%20in%20the%20navigation%20area).